# How to click a button in Tor Browser with Selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium, ubuntu, tor

I use Tor Browser with Selenium to automate a click on a button.

#### File *script.py*

```
from tbselenium.tbdriver import TorBrowserDriver
with TorBrowserDriver("/home/user/Selenium/tor-browser_en-US/") as driver:
driver.get('https://www.example.com/form.html')
```

How do I manage to perform a click on this button (excerpt from the HTML file)?

```
<form method="post" id="IdA" action="https://example.com/action.php"><input id='valid' name='valid' value='012.23945765955' type="hidden"><button class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" data-callback="onSubmit" id="IdA" style="background:url(https://www.example.com/button.gif);width:190px;height:58px;border:none;cursor:pointer;display:none;" type="submit"></button></form>
```

I tried this, but it did not work:

```
driver.findElement(By.Id("IdA")).click()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are trying to bypass a [CAPTCHA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA).

You can do this one of two ways. You can click the button by using a selector. For example, an XPath selector for a button with class "g-recpatcha". You can also just execute JavaScript code on the page to call the onSubmit() function.

So two options are:

1. driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='g-recaptcha']").click()
2. driver.execute_script("onSubmit("" + captchaToken + "")")

See the [reCAPTCHA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReCAPTCHA) callback on *[2captcha API, Solving Captchas](https://2captcha.com/2captcha-api#solving_captchas)*.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I also thought that `class="g-recaptcha"` has something to do with captcha, but when I run the site normally in the browser (TOR, Firefox) I do not see a captcha form. How can this be?

Comment: You do not see a captcha form? Or a captcha submit button? There is a thing such as invisible recaptcha.

Comment: Exactly, I do not see anything that has to do with captcha. Edit: But I understand the general method to bypass (refering to your url) but I do not know how I implement this concrete in my Python Script?

Comment: Do you see webpage data? Or do you have to click the button to get to it?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean with "webpage data"?

Comment: I mean, if you click the button (in your emulated selenium session), are you good to go? Or do you have to solve the captcha?

Comment: When I try the first option, I get `selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: Given xpath expression "//button[@class='g-recaptcha'" is invalid: SyntaxError: The expression is not a legal expression.`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211878/discussion-between-sri-and-user11325078).